# How is Fubini's Theorem being used in a Riemannian manifold?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, complex-geometry

As is well known, the Fubini theorem is very easy to be used in $\mathbb{R}^n$ due to the global coordinate of $\mathbb{R}^n$, because $dV_{s+t}=dV_{s}\times dV_{t}$ ($dV_{t}$ denotes the t-dimensional lebesgur measure).

However,  in a  Riemannian manifold $(X,\omega)$, we have no global coordinate.

Question: How can we split the volume form $dV_{\omega}$ into the product of 2 measures? Can the partition of unity work? If it can work, can anyone give some details?

Comment: "How can we split the volume form $dV_{\omega}$ into the product of 2 measures?" Why do you want to?

Comment: @NateEldredge The Fubini theorem essentially tell us the commutity of 2 integrals, i.e. $dV_s\times dV_t =dV_t\times dV_s$